# associating legend with geom_ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2

Taking the following simple example. I cannot get the legend to correctly associate the corresponding colors. Where have I gone wrong:

```
time <- as.factor(c('A','B','C','D'))
x <- c(1.00,1.03,1.03,1.06)
x.upper <- c(0.91,0.92,0.95,0.90)
x.lower <- c(1.11,1.13,1.17,1.13)
df <- data.frame(time, x, x.upper, x.lower)

time <- as.factor(c('A','B','C','D'))
x2 <- c(1.15,1.08,1.01,1.15)
x.upper2 <- c(1.10,1.00,1.01,0.95)
x.lower2 <- c(1.20,1.27,1.05,1.45)
df2 <- data.frame(time, x2, x.upper2, x.lower2)
```

And then to plot

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data = df, aes(time,x)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = df, aes(x=as.numeric(time), ymax=x.upper, ymin=x.lower), fill="T1", alpha=.5) +
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(time,x2)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = df2, aes(x=as.numeric(time), ymax=x.upper2, ymin=x.lower2), fill="T2", alpha=.5) +
  scale_fill_manual( "",
                     breaks = c("T1", "T2"),
                     values = c("pink", "blue"))
```

Or if we instead use `col` within the `aes`, the colors do not correctly associate

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data = df, aes(time,x)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = df, aes(x=as.numeric(time), ymax=x.upper, ymin=x.lower, col="T1"), fill="pink", alpha=.5) +
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(time,x2)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = df2, aes(x=as.numeric(time), ymax=x.upper2, ymin=x.lower2, col="T2"), fill="blue", alpha=.5) +
  scale_color_manual( "",
                     breaks = c("T1", "T2"),
                     values = c("pink", "blue"))
```

Comment: Do you want the legend to work with `fill=` even though you've left that out of the `aes()`? Can you be more precise what you mean when you say "the colors do not correctly associate." What do you expect to be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it what you want?

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data = df, aes(time,x)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = df, aes(x=as.numeric(time), ymax=x.upper, ymin=x.lower, fill="pink"), alpha=.5) +
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(time,x2)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = df2, aes(x=as.numeric(time), ymax=x.upper2, ymin=x.lower2, fill="blue"), alpha=.5) +
scale_fill_manual( "",
                     labels = c("T1", "T2"), values=c("pink"="pink","blue"="blue"))
```